# How to Get rid of title bar in Three20?

Tags: three20, modalviewcontroller, titlebar

I present a modal view controller in three20 framework,but the view is not full screen , and always hava a titleBar.how to get rid of this title,let my view is full screen.

How to get rid of Three20 TTTableviewController title bar?
when I present a TTTableviewController ,it always show a titlebar,i don't know how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

```
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0;
}
```

You can also call :

```
[super showBars:NO animated:NO];
```

but it's a private three20 function, so it would give you a compile notice.